# How do I compute $\langle r|P|\psi\rangle$ for a given state $|\psi\rangle$ with the associated wave function $\psi(r)=\langle r|\psi\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

How do I compute $\langle r|P|\psi\rangle$ for a particle in the state $|\psi\rangle$, with the associated wave function $\psi(r)=\langle r|P|\psi\rangle$, where $P$ is the momentum operator and $r$ is the position vector? I know how to apply $P$ on a simple $x$-dependent wave function, but I'm not sure how to compute this. I know it's supposed to be a scalar, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I never came across an impulse operator. Apparently nor did google, as it only turns up momentum operator, which as it happens is invariably denoted P. But then P is a vector operator.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I'll edit the question. What I meant to say is momentum operator, but I get those mixed up as in my native language they are switched. And yes, it is a vector operator, but I couldn't figure out how to write P or r as vectors here . So, how should I approach the problem then?

Comment: So, are you working in $\mathbb{R}^3$? With a three dimensional wave function, you want to find the action of the momentum operator in position space?

Comment: Yes, r is the position vector in three dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

It is
$$
\langle{\bf r}|\hat {\bf P}|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar\nabla \langle{\bf r}|\psi\rangle. 
$$
Here $\psi({\bf r})=\langle {\bf r}|\psi\rangle$ is the wavefunction and $|\psi\rangle$ is the abstract state vector.

Comment: But why doesn't it look like this? $$<r|P|\psi> = -ih<r| \nabla_r|\psi>$$ Since we are differentiating with respect to the <r| components, wouldn't writing it like this change the results?

Comment: You cannot write $\partial_r |\psi\rangle$ because $|\psi\rangle$ does not depend on $r$. It's only the wavefunction (i.e the $|r\rangle$ basis components of the abstract vector $|\psi\rangle$) that depend on $r$.  If you use the $|p\rangle$ basis then $\psi(p) =\langle{p}|\psi\rangle$ obeys $\langle p|\hat P|\psi \rangle =p \langle p|\psi\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

If you write $$\mathbf P = -\int d^3\mathbf x | \mathbf x \rangle i \nabla \langle \mathbf x|,$$ then you can just do the partial differentiation. I am not sure where the problem is, to be honest. Partial differentiation is just like ordinary differentiation. Perhaps the question has confused you with the notation, but $\mathbf r $ is just a different notation for $\mathbf x $

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I can write P like that.

Comment: I generally prefer this notation, because it keeps things technically correct and clear when acting on kets. The more usual notations are really just a shorthand for the same thing, but I am never quite happy with them. As you have found, confusion can arise if it is not remembered that they strictly only makes sense as an operator on a *particular representation* of Hilbert space